# Can't establish a ssh connection to my Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm having a

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

error when trying to ssh into my mac, from a linux VM

if I try with the verbose option I get this

```
ssh mac-user@192.168.1.11 -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.11 [192.168.1.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/linux-user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
```

I don't know what could be wrong, firewall options are ok.

Searching the web I found a temporary solution, disabling the "remote session" option and then using this command:

```
sudo $(which sshd) -Dd
```

Don't think its a propper answer.

This problem started when updating to Yosemite OSX.

Apreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using brew to install `openssh`. Then change `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` file to use `sshd` provided by brew. A better explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658950/upgrade-openssh-on-os-x-with-homebrew-for-pci-compliance

Answer (score 0):

config.vm.boot_timeout - The time in seconds that Vagrant will wait for the machine to boot and be accessible. By default this is 300 seconds. (got this from) [ServerFaqs](http://www.serverfaqs.com/wiki/connect-and-login/)

I'd increase this until you are able to vagrant ssh in.

Comment: sorry the link you gave me doesn't seem to have the answer, and not really sure what you mean by vagrant. I had no problems with this until the Yosimite update.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I deleted everything from SystemPrefereces->Security->Firewall and removed all services from SystemPreferences->Shared. Then I enabled remote login again. That fixed the problem in my case.

Comment: I deactivated the firewall but the problem persisted...